# Getting Error while trying to get data from a list [VB]

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm new to VB. I have created below method which returns a list.

```
Public Function WHSList(ByVal fp As Stream, ByVal importFile As String, ByVal ym As Integer) As List(Of Integer)


Return WHSLst

End Function
```

I'm trying to retrive the values of the list in a different method using the below code. However, I'm getting error.

```
 Private Sub AddFD45DM(ByVal dt As FD45DMDataSet.FD45DMDataTable, ByVal line As String, ByVal fileinfo As FD45DMFileInfo)

Dim WHSLst As New List(Of Integer) = WHSList(ByVal fp As Stream, ByVal importFile As String, ByVal ym As Integer)

 End Sub
```

Help Please.

Comment: What is the error exactly?

Comment: End of Statement Expected.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
Dim WHSLst As New List(Of Integer) = WHSList(ByVal fp As Stream, ByVal importFile As String, ByVal ym As Integer)
```

makes no sense.  Do you know what the `New` keyword is for?  It creates a new instance of the specified class by invoking a constructor.  It would never make sense to create a new instance if you were going to immediately discard it and replace it with one you got from elsewhere.  Remove the `New` keyword and it will work.  Only use `New` when you actually want a new instance.

Comment: So, suggest me the proper way to get the data from the list. I've created a method which returns a list. I'm trying to get the values of list in a different method.

Comment: Why would I do that?  This question is about why you are getting that error and I told you why and how to fix it.  If you have another question then then post it as another question.